# In QgsVectorDataProvider.deleteAttributes() set() problem

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

When I script the code:

```
def removeFields(provider, keepFieldNames, fileName, isBatch):
    """Remove fields other than keepFieldNames from shapefile fileName with provider."""
    toDelete = set()
    fields = provider.fields()
    for idx in range(fields.count()):
        name = fields.field(idx).name()
        if not name in keepFieldNames:
            toDelete.add(idx)
    if len(toDelete) > 0:
        OK = provider.deleteAttributes(fields)
```

I get this error:

```
File "C:/.../Topology.py", line 1028, in removeFields
    OK = provider.deleteAttributes(fields)
TypeError: QgsVectorDataProvider.deleteAttributes(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'set'
```

Comment: In your case, **fields** is **QgsFields** object; not a a list of integers (necessary for 'deleteAttributes' method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type at Python Console:

```
>>>help(QgsVectorDataProvider.deleteAttributes)
Help on built-in function deleteAttributes:

deleteAttributes(...)
    QgsVectorDataProvider.deleteAttributes(list-of-int) -> bool
```

it can be observed that you need a list of integers. So, when you type:

```
>>>fields
<qgis._core.QgsFields object at 0xa62abfa4>
```

it's clearly a **QgsFields** object; not a list of integers. Your integer list it should be **toDelete** variable produced by **set** function (assuming that this function is well implemented). Taking in account that, your code should run modified as:

```
.
.
.
    if len(toDelete) > 0:
        OK = provider.deleteAttributes(toDelete)
```

In my particular case, I corroborated that following adaptation of your code, in my own system, works properly.

```
>>>toDelete = []
>>>for idx in range(fields.count()):
...    name = fields.field(idx).name()
...    toDelete.append(idx)
>>>print toDelete
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

producing a desired integers list.

Comment: Yes you are definitely right. I also find a solution it works for me, as well. If you type todelete= list(), it works. Actually same thing